# How to use tensorflow dataset zip and string split function to get the same result?

Tags: tensorflow

How can i modify the code to make v1's structure the same as structure of v2?

```
import tensorflow as tf

a1_a2_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.constant(["c c a\ta b", "f e a g\tc c", "d\t", "c a\tb c"]))
label_reason_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.constant(["c c a\ta b", "f e a g\tc c", "d\t", "c a\tb c"]))
a1_a2_dataset = a1_a2_dataset.map(
    lambda src: (tf.string_split([src], delimiter='\t').values[0],
                 tf.string_split([src], delimiter='\t').values[1]))
label_reason_dataset = label_reason_dataset.map(
    lambda src: (tf.string_split([src], delimiter='\t').values[0],
                 tf.string_split([src], delimiter='\t').values[1]))

target_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((a1_a2_dataset, label_reason_dataset))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
table_initializer = tf.tables_initializer()
sess.run(table_initializer)
value = target_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
v1 = sess.run(value)
print("v1 = ", type(v1), v1)

a1_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.constant(["c c a", "f e a g", "d", "c a"]))
a2_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.constant(["a b", "c c", "", "b c"]))
label_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.constant(["c c a", "f e a g", "d", "c a"]))
reason_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.constant(["a b", "c c", "", "b c"]))
target_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((a1_dataset, a2_dataset, label_dataset, reason_dataset))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
table_initializer = tf.tables_initializer()
sess.run(table_initializer)
value = target_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
v2 = sess.run(value)
print("v2 = ", type(v2), v2)
```

For now, the test code above gives the following results:

```
v1 =  <class 'tuple'> ((b'c c a', b'a b'), (b'c c a', b'a b'))
v2 =  <class 'tuple'> (b'c c a', b'a b', b'c c a', b'a b')
```

But structure of v1 needs to be like v2. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution, but I am not quite into this one.

```
target_dataset = target_dataset.map(lambda a, b: (a[0], a[1], b[0], b[1]))
```

But if anybody has a better one, that will be so great!